# How to see what tag I created?

Tags: support, badges, taxonomist-badge

I have the the taxonomist badge, and I'd like to know what tag earned me that badge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the badge in your profile. It should take you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=262269), which will answer your question.

Comment: "No longer available"

Comment: Ooh. I forgot that we could see it for other users, so I didn't even bother to check the link.

Comment: I can't see the tag at all. It only says no longer available.

Comment: Quite so. Perhaps you created a tag that has since been merged with another one, but if so it's very hard to tell what it is.

Comment: am i correct in thinking that you can get this badge for posts tagged with a merged tag?